# Is there a method to disable the blue box when I click a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

I don't think it's required but here is the code for my button

```
JButton button = new JButton(text);
button.setFocusable(false);
button.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
button.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);
button.setBorderPainted(false);
```

The button forms just fine. A black background with orange text.
But when I click it, the button turns light-blue until I release the mouse button.

Is there a method say: `button.setHighlight(false);`

or something like that so that even when I click the button, it will keep its color or change to a color of my choice which I will just set to Color.BLACK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background color of `JButton` is set in the [look-and-feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html). You can alter the color via class [UIManager](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/UIManager.html). When you press the mouse button on the `JButton`, the `JButton` is said to be armed. Here is the code that sets the color of the `JButton` when it is armed.

```java
UIManager.put("Button.select", Color.orange);
```

This will make the `JButton` background orange when you press the mouse button when the mouse pointer is over the `JButton`.